# What is the meaning of '^' symbol in css?

Tags: css

What is the meaning of the '^' symbol in CSS? I found this on bootsrap.
note: [class^=border] <------ (see code below)

```
.bd-example-border-utils [class^=border] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: .25rem;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

Comment: It means begins with. It will match `.border-red` or `.bordered` for example, but would not match `.red-border`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bd-example-border-utils [class^=border]
```

This will select each div inside `.bd-example-border-utils` whose class attribute begins with: `border`

Answer (score 0):

The `^=` selector is used to select elements with a name that start with the specified value.

For example, the following example select all elements with a class attribute that begins with "border".

```css
[class^="border"] {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```